# SharedPreferences saving data twice

Tags: java, android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

```
private void setHighScore(){
    SharedPreferences.Editor scoreEdit = gamePrefs.edit();
    DateFormat dateForm = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
    String dateOutput = dateForm.format(new Date());
    String scores = gamePrefs.getString("highScores", "");
    if(scores.length() > 0) {
        List<Score> scoreStrings = new ArrayList<Score>();
        String[] exScores = scores.split("\\|");
        for(String eSc : exScores){
            String[] parts = eSc.split(" - ");
            scoreStrings.add(new Score(parts[0], Integer.parseInt(parts[1])));
        }
        Score newScore = new Score(dateOutput, score);
        scoreStrings.add(newScore);
        Collections.sort(scoreStrings);
        StringBuilder scoreBuild = new StringBuilder("");
        for (int x = 0; x < scoreStrings.size(); x++){
            if(x >= 10) break;
            if(x > 0) scoreBuild.append("|");
            scoreBuild.append(scoreStrings.get(x).getScoreText());
        }
        scoreEdit.putString("highScores", scoreBuild.toString());
        scoreEdit.commit();
    }else{
        scoreEdit.putString("highScores", ""+dateOutput+ " - " + score);
        scoreEdit.commit();
    }
}

public class MyCount extends CountDownTimer{
    public MyCount(long millisInFuture,long countDownInterval){
        super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        final TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
        time.setText("Times Up!");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(250);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        setHighScore();
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), score_screen.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished){
        final TextView time = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.time);
        time.setText("Left: " + millisUntilFinished/1000);
    }
}
public class score_screen extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_score_screen);
        TextView scoreView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scoreView);
        ImageButton home = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.home);
        SharedPreferences scorePrefs = getSharedPreferences(Game.GAME_PREFS, 0);
        String[] savedScores = scorePrefs.getString("highScores", "").split("\\|");
        StringBuilder scoreBuild = new StringBuilder("");
        for(String score : savedScores) {
            scoreBuild.append(score+"\n");
        }
        scoreView.setText(scoreBuild.toString());

        home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), ColorMatch.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am trying to save a highscore from my gamescreen after my timer is up. I am able to do this just fine and then when I re access my ArrayList for a second time the last score is resaved and I can't figure out why this is happening.

For example,after one game is finished with a score of 3170, it takes me to the high score screen where I see only one instance of the score. Then if I play a new game, or open my Highscores screen from the Main menu, I now see two instances of the same score. (3170) My guess is that it is double committing the score, but I cannot find a second .commit() in my highscore screen.

Comment: Debug it and you may find the problem. Maybe you are calling setHighscore twice.

Comment: I have checked this already with the search feature. The reason I believe it is a data issue is because it acts as I intend for it to right after the game has been finished and the score_screen activity is opened. The second score will only appear after the score_screen is opened for the second time.

Comment: Maybe your retained fragment is sending the same data again.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you may not be saving the high score to preferences twice.  I think the problem lies in that you are appending the high score.

Instead of appending the high score, you need to insert the high score into some position in the array.  Java arrays are a fixed size though, so you may want to consider using an ArrayList or LinkedList.

Comment: appending is necessary for me to place the string into the textbox on score_screen, I have narrowed the issue down to something within the setHighScore() method, and more particularly something to do with the SharedPreferences file most likely.

Answer (score 0):

In a method I didn't post, (OnDestroy()) I had a second instance of the method setHighScore() to store the score if someone backed out. When I removed this it stopped double writing making me believe that the problem was finish() references onDestroy() to close the activity.